# Command Block on Java Edition

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/give @a[scores={score=200}] emerald
```

This code gives everybody with a score of score = 200 an emerald, but I don't want it for everybody, I want it only for a specific person, how do I do this?
also, how do a make a command block that gives 20points per second of score to the player? cause mine only worked in a offline server so idk what i did wrong

Comment: Welcome to [Arqade](/tour)! Please see our [guide on asking Minecraft commands questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797), especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far.” Then, [edit] your post and add the requested information.

Comment: If that's what you are looking for, @a[name=<playername>,scores={score=200}] may work